# Python Product Chatbot

Tags: python, list, chatbot

HI i am trying to create a chat bot that asks for a certain price point and lists products inside that price point. however i am unsure how to do this. can anyone help.

```
price = input(f'do you have a specific price point for {product}s ')
price == int(price)
prices = {
    "rockymountianslayer" : int(1000),
    "norcostorm" : int(3000),
    "yetisb165" : int(11000),
    "yetisb100" : int(4070)
}
mountainbikes = ["rockymountianslayer", "norcostorm", "yetisb165", "yetisb100"]
print(f'{mountainbikes}')
```

i believe this part is the problem.

```
for prices > price:
    mountainbikes.remove()
    print (f'{mountainbikes}')
```

Comment: There's too many issues in your code. Why don't you start with a simple [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) and then do it all one step at a time, once you understand what the code you're writing actually does?

Comment: Please don't copy paste from Microsoft Word, Discord or any other application that does formatting. As it messes up the `"` and `'` quite heavily, as well as indentation issues. Ask yourself, "would I want to read this one-line of a mess?", if the answer is no, then neither do we : ) Make it pretty, and it'll be easier for us to help you and others. Probably a honest mistake, but keep it in mind when asking others for help - organize your help neatly so the one helping doesn't need to work twice as much for free :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
price = input(f'do you have a specific price point for {product}s ')
price == int(price)
prices = {
    "rockymountianslayer" : int(1000),
    "norcostorm" : int(3000),
    "yetisb165" : int(11000),
    "yetisb100" : int(4070)
}
mountainbikes = ["rockymountianslayer", "norcostorm", "yetisb165", "yetisb100"]
print(f'{mountainbikes}')

output = []
for i in mountainbikes:
    if prices[i] < price:
        output.append(i)
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks. you are the best?